# Complexity of this prime number search algorithm

Tags: algorithm, big-o

So I'm learning about Big O notation at the moment and I'm not sure how to work out what the Big O is of my following (deliberately inefficient) algorithm:

```
def getPrimes(n):

primes = [2]    

for i in range(3, n+1):
    remainder = True
    for j in primes:
        if(i % j == 0):
            remainder = False
    if(remainder == True):
        primes.append(i)
return primes
```

The amount of times the inner for loop will run will increase depending on how many items are inside the list, 'primes'. So how does that affect working out what the Big O is, if at all?

Answer (score 1):

Check for [Pi(n) function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeCountingFunction.html). It's approximation is n/ln(n).
Overall algorithm (a kind of Sieve of Eratosthenes implementation) complexity [is evaluated as O(n(loglog(n))](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Algorithm_complexity)

Comment: The algorithm given is less efficient that the sieve of erastothenes since it tests every number against every prime. I think it's inefficient enough to push it into a higher complexity class.

Answer (score 1):

Each i is tested against all primes less than i. Thus, the total amount of work done is:

```
sum(i=3..n)pi(i)
```

(where pi(i) is the number of primes less than i).

pi(n) is Theta(n/log n), so the amount of work done is in the same complexity class as:

```
sum(i=3..n)i/log(i)
```

I don't think there's any good approximation for this, but it's better than O(n^2) but not by much since log(i) grows slowly compared to i.